# Node.js Cluster not forking anything

Tags: node.js, server

I am trying to implement clustering in my Node.js application.

When I print out how many workers are spawned inside the for-loop with the `fork()` method, it prints out nothing.

The `coreCounter` variable also = 0 if I print it out.

Here is my code:

```
let cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    let coreCounter = require('os').cpus.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < coreCounter; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function () {
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    require('server.js');
}
```

I tried to npm install cluster and npm install os, it did not work, do I have to do npm install if I "require" something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `()` after the cpus.

See here:

```
let cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {

    let coreCounter = require('os').cpus().length;

    for (let i = 0; i < coreCounter; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', function () {
        cluster.fork();
    });
} else {
    //require('server.js');
    console.log('walla!')
}
```

You should not `npm install` NodeJS core modules.

P.S. I suggest you get some practice with NodeJS before implement clustering

Comment: Thank you very much :) I need as an assignment to improve the scalability/performance of my application, so I saw clustering. I don't find it that complicated to understand, is there something bad implementing it since I shouldn't do it before getting more practice?

Comment: I have no idea what is going on `server.js` so I can't tell.